# linking libusb-1.0.9 to codeblocks in windows

Tags: c

I downloaded the libusb-1.0.9 library from the net but it doesnt have any .lib file. It has a .def file although. The error it is showing is "uninitialized reference to libusb_init" . There is a .lib file that needs to added to the linker properties in settings of the compiler but I haven't been able to fix it.
It would be of great help if someone could help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to VS2008,

go to Project -> Project Properties -> Configuration -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependency, put your .lib name in addition ascendancy. And also copy .lib file your project directory.

If you do not have libusb-1-0-9.lb file then you can download from [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/?source=dlp)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the [code::blocks documentation regarding "Using project dependencies"](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=The_build_process_of_Code%3a%3aBlocks#Using_project_dependencies)?